# How do I make an oblique shadow?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uikit

I am adding a `NSShadow` object to a `NSMutableAttributedString` to draw it with a shadow around the string. But I see that `NSShadow` hasn't an attribute for setting the shadow inclination. It has only `shadowOffset`, `shadowColor` and `shadowBlurRadius` .

How do I make it oblique?